# Modifing data from uint8_t array very slow?

Tags: c++, c, x86, arm

I'm currently trying to optimize my code to run a bit faster. Currently it is taking about +30ms to update about 3776000 bytes. If I remove the `outPx` updates inside my function it runs at about 3ms meaning that the updates to `outPx` is what is making the function slower.

Any potential feedback on how to improve the speed of my function below would be greatly appreciated.

```
uint8_t* outPx = (uint8_t*)out.data;
for (int px=0; px<pxSize; px+=4)
    {
        newTopAlpha = (alpha*inPx[px+3]);

        if (0xff == newTopAlpha)
        {
            // top is opaque covers entire bottom

            // set copy over BGR colors
            outPx[px] = inPx[px];
            outPx[px+1] = inPx[px+1];
            outPx[px+2] = inPx[px+2];
            outPx[px+3] = 0xff; //Fully opaque
        }
        else if (0x00 != newTopAlpha)
        {
            // top is not completely transparent
            topAlpha = newTopAlpha/(float)0xff;
            bottomAlpha = outPx[px+3]/(float)0xff;
            newAlpha = topAlpha + bottomAlpha*(1-topAlpha);
            alphaChange = bottomAlpha*(1-topAlpha);

            outPx[px] = (uint8_t)((inPx[px]*topAlpha + outPx[px]*alphaChange)/newAlpha);
            outPx[px+1] = (uint8_t)((inPx[px+1]*topAlpha + outPx[px+1]*alphaChange)/newAlpha);
            outPx[px+2] = (uint8_t)((inPx[px+2]*topAlpha + outPx[px+2]*alphaChange)/newAlpha);
            outPx[px+3] = (uint8_t)(newAlpha*0xff);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're worried about 27 milliseconds?!

Comment: Also you need to remember that any decent compiler will optimise the code. If you remove the `outPx` lines, that will also remove the rest of the code, and likely the entire loop, as dead code. On the same note, the easiest way to speed up any code is to set your compiler's optimisation settings higher.

Comment: Without updating `outPx`, the function is doing hardly any writes. Are you sure that the code is not simply optimised away?

Comment: @Dave: That makes a frame rate of about 37 fps, that is not that high. Optimization is in order, IMHO.

Comment: What processor is this on?

Comment: @Jona: Can you not avoid both of the `if()` there? Or at least one of them? Compiles have better chance to optimize your loop if it does not contain conditionals.

Comment: @Jona: It seems to me that you could just keep the body of the second if and the function would still return the same results in the `outPx` array.

Comment: @wilx that assumes this is running in a frame-by-frame environment, but it looks like an image conversion to me which implies run-once, or run-offline at least. If this is frame-by-frame, then the obvious optimisation is to use the GPU.

Comment: @wilx: Whilst if's are painful, it is dwarfed by half a dozen float divides and about 10 multiplies.

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback. @Dave It is not fast enough, at best I need a 30fps meaning this function needs to run under 33msec. Plus I have some other overhead later in the code... So the faster the better.

Comment: @MatsPetersson it is running now on ARM processor but will also run on x86. This code is intended for Android mobile devices.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do your own alphablend on Android? Surely there is support from the Android system to perform this operation, that is highly optimized already [or using hardware, which is even better]. Reinventing the wheel is only worthwhile if you actually make a BETTER wheel than the existing one...

Comment: @Dave I'll look into compiler optimizations. How do I make the code run on GPU? Sorry GPU side of things is a bit new to me...

Comment: @Jona, @MatsPetersson: From what I can see with GCC 4.8, the `if` is as painful as it completely disables vectorization of the loop. If he removes the ifs, the vectorization does kick in. It is certainly worth a try and benchmark.

Comment: It would seem that your benchmarking method is incorrect. If this code runs on an ARM and takes 30ms (without any sluggish Windows OS in the background) there is just no way this calculation would take that long. Assuming you clock the ARM with at least a couple of MHz, this should take < 1 ms.

Comment: @Lundin Well... I'm on a Nexus4 Android device. I am using time.h android provided time class and I agree it should be really fast.

Comment: @wilx simply removing the if else makes the code 250ms slower :/

Comment: How do you build? Also when just copying over bytes use int and a mask to make that operation rather than 4 byte copies.

Comment: @Jona: What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: @wilx: vectorization may not help much on an ARM processor that probably doesn't have native float support. 

Jona: If it takes 250ms to do the WHOLE image, you are definitely doing something wrong. On Symbian OS with fairly well written AlphaBlend, and a much slower processor, we were able to get a good 15-20 fps in software. Are you enabling optimization when building the code?

Comment: @wilx I'm using the tool chain arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3 and I'm using no compiler optimization flags.

Comment: @Jona time.h is most likely based on some low-resolution timer. I have no idea how to properly benchmark Android programs, but I very much doubt this is how. Certainly there's some sort of API for benchmarking?

Comment: @Jona: That is simply silly. Supply at least `-O2`, better some `-march=foo` where `foo` is replaced by the target processor type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if this really is the bottleneck, and you can't use the GPU / built-in methods for some random reason, then there is a lot you can do:

```
uint8_t *outPx = (uint8_t*) out.data;
const int cAlpha = (int) (alpha * 256.0f + 0.5f);
for( int px = 0; px < pxSize; px += 4 ) {
    const int topAlpha = (cAlpha * (int) inPx[px|3]) >> 8; // note | not + for tiny speed boost

    if( topAlpha == 255 ) {
        memcpy( &outPx[px], &inPx[px], 4 ); // might be slower than per-component copying; benchmark!
    } else if( topAlpha ) {
        const int bottomAlpha = (int) outPx[px|3];
        const int alphaChange = (bottomAlpha * (255 - topAlpha)) / 255;
        const int newAlpha    = topAlpha + alphaChange;

        outPx[px  ] = (uint8_t) ((inPx[px  ]*topAlpha + outPx[px  ]*alphaChange) / newAlpha);
        outPx[px|1] = (uint8_t) ((inPx[px|1]*topAlpha + outPx[px|1]*alphaChange) / newAlpha);
        outPx[px|2] = (uint8_t) ((inPx[px|2]*topAlpha + outPx[px|2]*alphaChange) / newAlpha);
        outPx[px|3] = (uint8_t) newAlpha;
    }
}
```

The main change is that there is no floating point arithmetic any more (I might have missed a `/255` or something, but you get the idea). I also removed repeated calculations and used bit operators where possible. Another optimisation would be to use fixed-precision arithmetic to change the 3 divides into a single divide and 3 multiply/bitshifts. But you'd have to benchmark to confirm that actually helps. The `memcpy` *might* be faster. Again, you need to benchmark.

Finally, if you know something about the images, you could give the compiler hints about the branching. For example, in GCC you can say `if( __builtin_expect( topAlpha == 255, 1 ) )` if you know that most of the image is solid colour, and `alpha` is 1.0.

---

Update based on comments:

And for the love of sanity, *never* (**never**) benchmark with optimisations turned off.

Comment: `>> 8` divides by 256, not 255. Also, manually adding bit operators is most likely premature optimization, the compiler will be able to do this for you. Getting rid of the float should be be the only manual optimization needed.

Comment: @Lundin yes, that's why I multiplied `cAlpha` by 256 instead of 255.

Comment: Aha, I missed that. Nevertheless, obscure optimizations like these shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Dave well I'm a bit new to caring a lot about optimizations in when writing C/C++ code... I feel a bit dumb for not knowing better :/

Comment: @Ludin The compiler can't make optimisations like that (changing the preceding line to 256 even changes behaviour slightly!) and replacing 3776000 divisions for 3776000 bitshifts is enough of a performance difference to warrant it IMO. But anyway, the real issue here is bad benchmarking, so it seems all this has become moot.

Comment: @Dave thanks for your optimized function it is a lot faster! I have just found a good way to profile my code. I'll be using that for further tests. As of now using my crappy profiling it is at ~20ms. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`uint8_t` is an *exact width* integer type, meaning that you demand the compiler to allocate exactly that much memory for your type. If your system has an alignment requirement, this may cause the code to run slower.

Change `uint8_t` to `uint_fast8_t`. This tells the compiler that you want this variable to be 8 bits if possible, but that it is ok to use a larger size if it makes the code faster.

Apart from that, there are lots of things that could cause bad performance, in which case you need to state what system and compiler you are using.

Comment: Except the data probably needs to be 8-bit pixel-data when finished. I'm pretty sure that, like my comment above, this is not an issue. The issue is all the floating point calculations.

Comment: @MatsPetersson The final result could be fixed with a cast to uint8_t at the end. And it seems likely that the floats are the culprit, although without knowing which specific system that the code runs on, it is hard to manually optimize anything. The system might not even have a FPU, for all we know.

Comment: Hence, I did ask in the comment above "what processor is this for"

Comment: Interesting optimization. I'll try it out now. The CPU I'm using is ARM but I would like to also make it run on x86.

Comment: @Jona Then you do have an alignment requirement. However, this little optimization alone doesn't explain the astronomic slowness of 30ms.

Comment: @Lundin I tested your suggestion but it made it about the same. I'm wondering if I should simply make my data array mapped to uint32_t to be aligned? And simply modify the bytes for the individual colors and alpha?

Comment: @Jona Based on all the comments, it would seem to me that the real problems here are 1) you haven't enabled optimization, and 2) you benchmark with a low resolution "time of the day" header.

Comment: +1 This **CAN** be as important.  Does the CPU have an FPU?  We don't know.  Memory is as important as floating point, especially with something as memory intensive as *video*.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing floating point divides, and conversion from byte to float and back again. If you use integer math, it is highly likely more efficient.

Even doing this simple conversion to multiply instead of divide may help quite a bit:

```
newAlpha = 1/(topAlpha + bottomAlpha*(1-topAlpha)); 

... 

outpx = (uint8_t)((inPx[px]*topAlpha + outPx[px]*alphaChange)*newAlpha);
```

Multiply tends to be much faster than divide.

Comment: +1 If the CPU has an FPU, it could actually slow down the code.  The FPU and integer unit may pipeline, for instance. Probably there is never an *answer* to an optimization question.  Of course this is good advice to try.